# How to extract the ratio between two variables in a linear system?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a simple linear system using Mathematica (see the image below). I understand there are five variables (A1, A2, B1, B2, A3) and only four equations, so I cannot solve them. I want to know how to get the ratio between A1 and A3 using Mathematica.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

Comment: You should look at the *Mathematica* command `Reduce`.  Also, if you expect help, you'll need to provide the equations in *Mathematica* form rather than just an image.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use indexed variables and use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the indexed variables as subscripts

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {A, B, k};

(eqns = {A[1] + B[1] == A[2] + B[2],
     -k[0] A[1] + k[0] B[1] ==
      -k[1]/μ[ω] A[2] + k[1]/μ[ω] B[2],
     A[2] E^(-I k[1] d) + B[2] E^(I k[1] d) ==
      A[3] E^(-I k[0] d),
     -k[1]/μ[ω] A[2] E^(-I k[1] d) +
       k[1]/μ[ω] B[2] E^(I k[1] d) ==
      -k[0] A[3] E^(-I k[0] d)}) //
  Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Since you want the ratio `A[1]/A[3]`, include both `A[1]` and `A[3]` in the four variables to be solved for

```
(sol = Solve[eqns, {A[1], A[3], B[1], B[2]}][[1]] // Simplify)//
  Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

The `ratio` is

```
(ratio = A[1]/A[3] /. sol // FullSimplify) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]